# How can i center the arrows on a slideshow? leaving a100px of distance between both and staying in the same place with different widths

Tags: html, css, slideshow

The arrows are centered horizontally and vertically, but i want them centered horizontally with 100px of distance between prev and next arrows.
So they won't be sticked to the edge of the window.

I have tried to add the arrows on a div and then center them horizontally and vertically but can't make it work.

```js
(function() {

  init(); //on page load - show first slide, hidethe rest

  function init() {

    parents = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container');

    for (j = 0; j < parents.length; j++) {
      var slides = parents[j].getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = parents[j].getElementsByClassName("dot");
      slides[0].classList.add('active-slide');
      dots[0].classList.add('active');
    }
  }

  dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot'); //dots functionality

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {

    dots[i].onclick = function() {

      slides = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

      for (j = 0; j < this.parentNode.children.length; j++) {
        this.parentNode.children[j].classList.remove('active');
        slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
        if (this.parentNode.children[j] == this) {
          index = j;
        }
      }
      this.classList.add('active');
      slides[index].classList.add('active-slide');

    }
  }
  //prev/next functionality
  links = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow-container a');

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      current = this.parentNode;

      var slides = current.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = current.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      curr_slide = current.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0];
      curr_dot = current.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
      curr_slide.classList.remove('active-slide');
      curr_dot.classList.remove('active');
      if (this.className == 'next') {

        if (curr_slide.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('mySlides')) {
          curr_slide.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active-slide');
          curr_dot.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          slides[0].classList.add('active-slide');
          dots[0].classList.add('active');
        }

      }

      if (this.className == 'prev') {

        if (curr_slide.previousElementSibling) {
          curr_slide.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active-slide');
          curr_dot.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('active-slide');
          dots[slides.length - 1].classList.add('active');
        }

      }

    }

  }
})();
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.active-slide {
  display: block;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x350" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: copied your code to a jsfiddle and seemed to be cenered with bootstrap, but i lost the link. try it ou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this might be to place your arrows within a flexbox. With flexbox you can center the flex items (the arrows), and then set a margin on one of your arrows to separate these by the desired width - in this example, 100px:

If you require different spacing on different carousels, you can target the individual carousel arrows and add classes to these to get them to behave differently. The first example uses the class of center that has the flex attributes to center the arrows, and the second example has the class of between that has the flex attribute for space-between to push the arrows to the edge of the box.

```js
index = 0;
parents = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container');
(function() {

  init(); //on page load - show first slide, hidethe rest

  function init() {

    // parents = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container');

    for (j = 0; j < parents.length; j++) {
      var slides = parents[j].getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = parents[j].getElementsByClassName("dot");
      slides[0].classList.add('active-slide');
      slides[0].classList.remove('fade');
      dots[0].classList.add('active');
    }
  }

  dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot'); //dots functionality

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {

    dots[i].onclick = function() {

      slides = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

      for (j = 0; j < this.parentNode.children.length; j++) {
        this.parentNode.children[j].classList.remove('active');
        slides[j].classList.remove('active-slide');
        if (this.parentNode.children[j] == this) {
          index = j;
        }
      }
      this.classList.add('active');
      slides[index].classList.add('active-slide');

    }
  }


  //prev/next functionality
  links = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow-container a');

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      current = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

      var slides = current.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = current.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      var curr_slide = current.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0];
      curr_dot = current.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
      curr_slide.classList.remove('active-slide');
      curr_dot.classList.remove('active');
      if (this.className == 'next') {

        if (curr_slide.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('mySlides')) {
          curr_slide.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active-slide');
          curr_dot.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          slides[0].classList.add('active-slide');
          dots[0].classList.add('active');
        }

      }

      if (this.className == 'prev') {

        if (curr_slide.previousElementSibling) {
          curr_slide.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active-slide');
          curr_dot.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('active-slide');
          dots[slides.length - 1].classList.add('active');
        }

      }

    }

  }
})();
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.center>.next {
  margin-left: 100px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.active-slide {
  display: block;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.arrowWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 42px);
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowFlex {
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/350" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowWrap">
    <div class="arrowFlex center">
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/350" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowWrap">
    <div class="arrowFlex between">
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! It works well! Keeps the buttons at the same distance and is applied in different widths. However, I have several slide shows and I think this function affects the alignment of all the arrow buttons in all slide shows, right? Is there any way to avoid that?
I applied ArrowFlex in a slide show but I need the arrows in different positions in other slide shows.
And the arrows appear in a different position from where i had left them.
Hope you understand what I meant and you can help me.

Comment: Yes, because you're using the same classes for the different carousels, they will all behave in the same way. There are many ways to target specific elements. You can add extra classes to them, or an id, and in your CSS define how these are to behave differently. I've updated the snippet to show the first carousel with a class to center the arrows, and the other one has a class to have the arrows on the edge of the carousel. This probably won't be the solution you're looking for, but maybe this gives you the sort of idea for what you can do.

Comment: After trying many times finally I could find the way to solve my problem. Now i have my multiple carousels with the arrows where i want to. Your help has been soooo useful, thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad you got it to work. If you feel that this answer helped you, you could accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). This lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and others who have a similar problem, might find the solution useful to them too.